# Wordpress /page_id= order

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

When using plan structure link like: https://example.com/?p=123

Wordpress gives random number, not by the order. In some cases I need to know the page id in advance. So is there are any way to get rid of the order WP gives to the link id?

Comment: that is  the id from the wp_posts database row where that post is stored, not a random number.

Comment: Can I know in advance what number will get the next page that will be published?

Comment: essentially its at whatever count the table is at, the same table is used for all post types so it would be a hard ask.

Comment: You can make a custom rewrite_rule i think and see if it doesnt break the site. Rewrite routing https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/